# Paste from clipboard without triggering iabbr

Tags: abbreviations

I have the following in my .vimrc

```
iabbr Alice Bob
```

I have copied the text of Alice in Wonderland from Project Gutenberg using my system clipboard and would like to paste it into a new file in vim.

I would normally enter insert mode and then CMD-V, but if I do that, iabbr will trigger and make lots of replacements in the text.

Is there a way of pasting from the system clipboard without triggering the iabbr?

Comment: I don't know what your 'CMD-V` is doing. Try e.g. using `:set paste` before pasting

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - :set paste turned out to be exactly the right answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It would be great if anyone turned the comment into an answer so it can be accepted, question closed, etc. Thanks!

Comment: A proper answer should possibly also mention 'pastetoggle' and bracketed-paste mode, which may make pasting easier.

Answer (score 1):

To insert the system clipboard's content into your buffer, use `"*p` in normal mode (or `<C-R>*<CR>` in insert mode).

The special `*` register contains the clipboard's contents. See `:help clipboard`. (There's also its brother the `+` register that contains the current selection on systems that support it, e.g. Linux)

Whatever you're doing to paste from the clipboard will appear as if you typed it in. This is probably because you flood Vim with a stream of characters instead of accessing the clipboard through Vim. As mentioned in the comment, `:set paste` will prevent this.

A somewhat related improvement is `:set mouse=a`. See `:help 'mouse'` for an explanation of how this will make mouse selections work intuitively.

Note that clipboards work completely different on different operating systems so you should take yours into account.

Comment: With proper term support (_i.e._, bracketed paste), just using the terminal's paste should automatically trigger `paste` as needed.